# Setup a cronjob for PHP script in ubuntu 16.04 & PHP 7.0

Tags: 16.04, cron, php7

It is making me mad that I want to setup a cronjob for PHP script in ubuntu 16.04.

I enter this command in terminal

```
$ crontab -e
```

Then I choose nano editor which is recommended by ubuntu. Then I enter the blow  line into that. Then I press control+C, it asking Y/N for save. I press Y and F2 for close.

```
* */2 * * * root php /var/www/html/script.php
```

other tries are,

```
* */2 * * * /var/www/html/script.php
* */2 * * * root /var/www/html/script.php
```

After I restart cron using below command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

Then I check crontab list `crontab -l` it says no cron job set for the root user.

I tried to directly create a crontab.txt file into the cron.hourly / cron.d directory with one of the above line.

I tried numerous forum and all says `crontab -e`  then enter or create crontab file inside cron directory. Nothing is helping me. I am scratching my head.

What is the correct way to create cronjob for php script in ubuntu 16.04 & php version 7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crontab -e` should not have the `root` part, which specifies the username (`crontab -e` already edits a specific user's crontab).

If you want to run as root, do `sudo crontab -e`,  and use:

```
* */2 * * * php /var/www/html/script.php
```

or create a file in `/etc/cron.d` containing:

```
* */2 * * * root php /var/www/html/script.php
```

Comment: what should be the file name? I give file name `php` or `crontab.txt`. But nothing coming out `crontab -l`

Comment: Files in `/etc/cron.d` won't show up in `crontab -l`.  Filenames can have alphabets, digits, underscore and hyphens (no `.`, sorry). No, you shouldn't have to restart anything. What does apache have to do with anything?

Comment: Do I need to restart the apache2?

Answer (score 1):

Crontab is used like this: `crontab -u <username> -e`. `-u <username>` part can be omitted for the current user. If you want to use it for root user you can use `sudo crontab -e`. Then you type your schedule arrangments `* */2 * * *` and the last argument in line is the line to run your script. When you finish, crontab writes the output whether you have installed the job successfully or not. There are some things you need to consider about the last argument.

1. Do you have php-cli installed? If not php will not work from command line. (`sudo apt-get install php7-cli`)
2. When you have php-cli installed, make sure crontab finds the php executable. crontab does not necessarily has the same $PATH. Type `which php` and use the full path in crontab `* */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/script.php`. Well `/usr/bin` shall be in crontab's path. This step is probably not needed, but it does not hurt.

Apache does not have anything to do with your crontab scripts because php scripts are run from command line in this case. You may have problems with PHP script if you rely on some apache related data in your script, which are not accessible in command line.

Comment: php7-cli installed already... And I am very sure that no problem with php script. Because I am keep manually running the task and finishing the job perfectly. So I want to auto the script running.